# undefined reference to 'gst_app_src_ser_caps' while crosscompiling for raspberry pi

Tags: cmake, gstreamer, cross-compiling

While trying to do a cross-compilation i run into undefined reference to multiple gstreamer functions. My cmake project contains two projects A and B and a test project to test the two project. The problem comes when the linking happens in the test project

```
/x-tools/aarch64-rpi3-linux-gnu/bin/ld.bfd: ProjectA/libProject.so : undefined reference to 'gst_app_src_set_caps'
```

How do I solve this issue?

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
include_directories(~/Project/inc/) 
include_directories(~/Project/inc/gstreamer-1.0/) 
link_directories(~/Project/lib/)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} ~/Project/lib;/usr/lib) 
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ~/x-tools/aarch64-rpi3-linux-gnu/aarch64-rpi3-linux-gnu/sysroot) 
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ~/x-tools/aarch64-rpi3-linux-gnu) 
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(ProjectB) 
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(ProjectA) 
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(project-test)
```

This is my CMAKE file for the full project inc has my headers and lib has the so files brought over from a rasberry pi

I am working on an Ubuntu 18.04 and using a cross-compiler aarch64-rpi3-linux-gnu. The issue is I am not able to use 'apt-get install' on this PC so I have manually copied the libraries and so files and kept them in a folder

Comment: The error message tells you, that library file (binary!) `ProjectA/libProject.so` contains the symbol, which is defined neither in the library nor in the libraries it is linked with. The problem could be with your toolchain file, with your project (`CMakeLists.txt`) or with your environment. Your question post contains information about none of these aspects, so it is impossible to help you. You may start debugging with inspecting the exact (linker) command line which creates `ProjectA/libProject.so` and checking whether any of the linked library contains the missed symbol.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I am sorry for not prof=viding enough info, I am quite new at doing this, I am working on an Ubuntu 18.04 and using a cross-compiler aarch64-rpi3-linux-gnu. The issue is I am not able to use 'apt-get install' on this PC so I have manually copied the libraries and so files and kept them in a folder

Comment: No, do not post code in the comments. Instead, [edit] the **question post** and add the code (and relevant information) into it. On Stack Overflow *comments* are temporary things and used mostly for clarification *requests*. But clarifications should be done in the question post itself. Finally, a question post should contain all information, which is sufficient to answer it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev is this better? If there is any other info needed please tell I'll add. Thanks a lot

Comment: The part of  `CMakeLists.txt` you show describes none aspect from the noted in the error message. It describes neither creation of `Project` **library**, nor its linkage with GStreamer. The only thing that exhibited by your `CMakeLists.txt` is that you **incorrectly** setup cross-compiling. Correct way is to use a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling).